# Blazor pages in TOR Browser not rendering

Tags: tor, blazor-server-side

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Blazor Server-Side Application.

Recently a user has complained, that it does not work with the TOR Browser.

So I tried it out and had to find out, it works in only ~50% of all cases.
Every time I tried, I requested a new circuit for the request.
When it worked, everything was fine and even the speed was not that bad.
But if not, first, the tab is loading the source, showing the favicon and then nothing happens for a while.
Sometimes, if you are patient enough it looks like the first render happens, but the second and so on for all the async operations never happens.

Is there a difference between the TOR nodes, that prevents Blazor pages from working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Tor by default blocks javascript, which blazor signalR is based on, so it can't effectively communicate with the server, disable noscript.
Also k